# Resolving "Could not connect to the reCAPTCHA service. Please check your internet connection and reload to get a reCAPTCHA challenge."

Tags: recaptcha

I was trying google Recaptcha on the Safari browser which couldn't work (It's working on any other browser like Edge, IE, Firefox, Chrome). After waiting for a minute it returns:

> Could not connect to the reCAPTCHA service.
>
> Please check your internet connection and reload to get a reCAPTCHA
>   challenge.

[image: error]
You could reproduce this on https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo using [latest Windows Safari Browser](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68836/where-can-i-download-safari-for-windows): http://appldnld.apple.com/Safari5/041-5487.20120509.INU8B/SafariSetup.exe

The main problem was that I can't checkmark the captcha and select the pictures, any idea to resolve this?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue. If yes, pls share.

Comment: I am experiencing this issue using a webview inside an android app.

Answer (score 14):

We were having random users experience this in our org even on sites with hidden recaptcha.  We have a proxy server I suspect is the main cause.

For some reason, simply going to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo and checking the box would fix the recaptcha on the offending site(s).  I don't know how long the fix will last though.  Out of 90 people we had 3 users reporting issues so it wasn't a widespread issue.

Comment: Weirdly it solved the issue for me as well! (tried clearing all cache/cookies for all google related domain and it didn't work) - probably some internal Google stuff on their backends

Comment: this solved my issue too, it does not makes any sense but works. Note that if you have 2-3 different pages, you have to open the page that throws the error then do this check, once per every page.

Comment: This resolved for me too, bizarrely. Also behind a proxy server though other users don't seem to experience the issue - very strange.

Answer (score 7):

I've experienced this issue as well. For me the solution was to pause / disable addblocker. Apparently the request url for the recaptcha script is changed when using this blocker
([https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/{addblocker}/recaptcha__en_gb.js](https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/%7Baddblocker%7D/recaptcha__en_gb.js)).

When checking console errors, this request url is unavailable.

So when I disabled the addblocker, the reCaptcha is working just fine.

Answer (score 6):

Here my two cents on the issue
After a few hours researching and experimenting with Safari's configuration, I discovered the root cause.

[image: cross-site tracking, Recaptcha problem]

In Preferences on Privacy tab, you will find the option "Prevent cross-site tracking", if this option is checked then you will see the error message in the reCaptcha section. According to Apple support this is what they say that happens when it is checked:

> Unless you visit and interact with the third-party content provider as a first-party website, their cookies and website data are deleted.

Complete explanation: [Prevent cross-site tracking in Safari](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/prevent-cross-site-tracking-sfri40732/mac)

If you uncheck the option and reload the page, then you will be able to use the reCaptcha control. It seems it depends on how your website is communicating with the reCaptcha service, if it is from a website you are creating and how it detects the source connection or maybe if the website has an SSL on it. Maybe Google itself is the only one who can completely clarify what is going on under the hood, in the meantime, this is what I know:

When we have this enabled, it blocks the cookie creation and website data, in this case a specific session storage key called "rc::b" is not created in Safari browser and so reCaptcha is no able to connect to its source to do what it wants. For some reason Safari blocks this one but allows the "rc::a" cookie.

These would be my recommendations for now:

1. Uncheck the "Prevent cross-site tracking" option.
2. Or you can open a Private tab or Incognito tab and it will go through without issues.

Hope this helps to those out there looking for a solution to this annoying roadblock.

Comment: I appreciate this information - makes sense.  However I cannot reproduce the issue (which a customer reported) using Safari 13 or 14 with "prevent cross-site tracking" enabled.  My best guess is that Apple has recently fixed this issue by exempting recaptcha, but my customer has not updated their Safari in the last few months.